# How to have code coverage for test packages in Go

Tags: go, testing, code-coverage

I'm trying to generate the code coverage for my `golang` project.

My setup is as follows:

```
- my_project
|  - my_package
|  |  - my_dev_file.go
|  |  - test
|  |  |  - my_dev_file_test.go
```

This setup allows to test the code from the point of view of a client that would call the package, without knowing anything about its internal implementation. At the sale time, dev dirs and test dirs are clearly separated which enforces global readability of the project.

The test code looks like this:

```
import (
    "..."
    "testing"
    "path-to/my_package"
    "..."
)

func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("should do something", func(t *testing.T) {
       my_package.MyStruct.DoSomething()

       // test something...
    })
}
```

This setup works fine as far as testing is concerned.

However, i can't seem to be able to generate a coverage report. Coverage is `0%` whatever command i launch, starting with:

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out ./.../test
OK path-to/test       0.005s  coverage: 0.0% of statements
OK other-path-to/test 0.007s  coverage: 0.0% of statements
```

I'm looking for a way to generate proper code coverage without compromising the way the project is organized.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Testing and line coverage is done  on a per-package-basis. Imported packages are not considered to be under test. Reorg as your project is badly organsied there is nothing to "compromise".

Comment: I see your point. Yet, I don't get the logic: golang offers the possibility to have the tests in separate packages as production code, which makes total sens. Why offering this possibility if you could not compute code coverage afterwards???

Comment: No. Why it is technically possible to write a test for package a in package a (with a not b_test) this is absolutely not recommended or encouraged. You are misusing the tooling. BTW: The language is called "Go".

Answer (score 2):

You should run

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out ./...
```

Comment: I tried, but it does not work. If it works for you, then this might mean that my problem comes from somewhere else. Actually I have developed a small "assertion" library so I don't have to write over and over again the same assertions. This might be my problem... I need to test this.

Comment: Actually, I don't have any error message!! Tests are smooth and OK. I just don't have any coverage...

Comment: Just install visual studio code and install golang pluggin then go to the test file and then right click and select toggle test coverage in the current packageit will show you the coverage graphically within the code as well as in the terminal

Comment: @ASHWINRAJEEV hey dude, thx for your comment. However this is not a good practice for my project, since I need to automate everything. Code Coverage cannot depend on installing an IDE as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this flag on your command `-coverpkg ./...`. This is the command I use to run the tests:

```
go test -coverprofile coverage.out ./... -coverpkg ./...
```